# Is card-swipe hardware payment system-specific?

Tags: paypal, credit-card, payment-processing, square

Looking at how most card swipe hardware for use with smartphones uses an interface as simple as the audio port, I'm wondering - is there an integration standard they're relying on?

Put another way - could someone use the great looking [Square stand](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00G5IPJ52) with a different payment provider?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but these devices are not standardized; each solution is custom and the devices will not interoperate.